# MySQL - Joining table with different charset in a view

Tags: mysql, schema, view, character-set

I want to join tables from two different schemas. But the problem is both schemas follow different charset **utf8_general_ci** & **utf8mb4_unicode_ci**.

When i do a join on both tables, it works. But, when i create a view with same query and do a select on the view, it throws an error

```
Error Code: 1267. Illegal mix of collations (utf8mb4_general_ci,IMPLICIT) and (utf8mb4_unicode_ci,IMPLICIT) for operation '='
```

Comment: Specify collations in the condition for both columns explicitly. Like `WHERE t1.f1 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci = t2.f2 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci`.

Comment: Getting Error Code: 1253. COLLATION 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci' is not valid for CHARACTER SET 'utf8'

Comment: Select some compatible collation (and safe for you, of course). Or use explicit CONVERT() for one or both columns.

Comment: Could you explain, why it's happening on selecting from a view, but not directly when selecting with joins ?

Comment: I don't know. Try to study https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/charset.html - maybe you'll find something...

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 4):

Try using **CONVERT()** to change the Chararcter Set first:

```
ON Convert(t1.f1 USING utf8mb4) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci = t2.f2
```